# Making a free and premium version of the same app is it better to make one app or 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

I have an app I am working on that I want to be free but with ads. I want to also have a premium version that does not have ads but costs a small amount to purchase ($1.99). I want to know if other developers, especially those that have distributed such an app, if it is a better practice to create 2 apps or if it is better to make one app with an upgrade option built-in. I like the idea of having a separate listing for the paid app but I can see where that could be a lot of extra work to maintain a separate app for such a small feature difference.

Comment: if you did decide to have 2 apps, you would not maintain 2 different versions/projects, you would just have a flag (probably a bool) set somewhere in your codebase that enables or disables the premium stuff. Also, no one can tell you a definitive answer on this question, there are too many factors involved

Comment: What did you end up with? 2 different published apps (free + paid)? I want to do the same  for a Cordova based application, because I could not find a solid working inapp purchase plugin.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner. I went with a single app with ads with a payment option to upgrade. When the user data is loaded I set a bool variable that is used in my `showads() ` method that prevents the ads from showing if the user is a "premium" member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all,
if you are going to develop apps for appstore, you can't create 2 apps have the same basic features but one has pro features
that's according to app-store review guidelines 4.3 spam
says....

> 4.3 Spam
>
> Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has
> different versions for specific locations, sports teams, universities,
> etc., consider submitting a single app and provide the variations
> using in-app purchase. Also avoid piling on to a category that is
> already saturated; the App Store has enough fart, burp, flashlight,
> fortune telling, dating, and Kama Sutra apps, etc. already. We will
> reject these apps unless they provide a unique, high-quality
> experience. Spamming the store may lead to your removal from the
> Developer Program.
> Blockquote

if not.

then second.

both will work fine,
there are games like limbo have free and paid versions on google play

that's your decision anyway,

if there is a lot of difference between free and paid,

if it's just about unlocking some features and remove ads,

it's a simple answer. if both of options will give the same functionality,
choose the easiest way

and "separate listing for the paid app" not a good idea, why?
@KiloKw2 mention to that

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your personal preference. If you would want to create 2 apps then you need to also have two unity projects at once and if you would integrate the premium stuff as paid expansion then you would need add a code into the game which enables them if the used bought them. I would personally go with having just one game with a built in paid expansion as I find easier that way. Having two of the same apps at once just complicates everything for no reason